# How to replace `qux$foo$bar` with `qux[["foo"]][["bar]]`? (dollar subsetting to brackets subsetting)

Tags: r, regex, gsub

In a R script (that I would read with `readLines`), I want to replace every occurence of `qux$foo$bar` with `qux[["foo"]][["bar]]`. But I'm not a regex master.

I started with this regex:

```
> gsub("(\\w*)(\\$)(\\w*)", '\\1[["\\3"]]', "qux$foo$bar; input$test$a$a") %>% cat
qux[["foo"]][["bar"]]; input[["test"]][["a"]][["a"]]
```

Nice. But I also want to handle the case of backticks. So I tried:

```
> gsub("(\\w*)(\\$)`{0,1}(\\w*)`{0,1}", '\\1[["\\3"]]', "qux$`foo`; bar$`baz`; x$uvw") %>% cat
qux[["foo"]]; bar[["baz"]]; x[["uvw"]]
```

Looks correct. But between the backticks, there could be a space, and the previous way does not work in this case. So I tried the following, which neither does not work:

```
gsub("(\\w*)(\\$)`{0,1}(.*)`{0,1}", '\\1[["\\3"]]', "qux$`fo o`") %>% cat
qux[["fo o`"]]
```

Could you help to find the right regex pattern? It seems that instead of `\\w` I need something which means *match a "word that can contain spaces"*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```r
gsub('(\\w*)(?|\\$`([^`]*)`|\\$([^\\s$]+))', '\\1[["\\2"]]', x, perl=TRUE)
## Or
gsub('\\$`([^`]*)`|\\$([^\\s$]+)', '[["\\1\\2"]]', x, perl=TRUE)
```

See the [regex #1 demo](https://regex101.com/r/dwnCkL/5) and [regex #2 demo](https://regex101.com/r/dwnCkL/6). *Details*:

- `(\w*)` - Group 1 (`\1`): zero or more word chars
- `` (?|$`([^`]*)`|$([^\s$]+)) `` - a branch reset group matching either

  - `` $`([^`]*)` `` - `$`, backtick, Group 2 (`\2`) capturing zero or more non-backtick chars, and a backtick.
  - `|` - or
  - `$([^\s$]+)` - `$`, then Group 2 (`\2`) capturing one or more chars other than whitespace and `$`

See [the R demo](https://ideone.com/6L105X):

```r
x <- c('qux$foo$bar','qux$foo$bar; input$test$a$a','qux$`foo`; bar$`baz`; x$uvw','qux$`fo o`', 'q_ux$f_o_o$b.a_r')
gsub('(\\w*)(?|\\$`([^`]*)`|\\$([^\\s$]+))', '\\1[["\\2"]]', x, perl=TRUE)
## Or
## gsub('\\$`([^`]*)`|\\$([^\\s$]+)', '[["\\1\\2"]]', x, perl=TRUE)
```

Output:

```r
[1] "qux[[\"foo\"]][[\"bar\"]]"                                     
[2] "qux[[\"foo\"]][[\"bar;\"]] input[[\"test\"]][[\"a\"]][[\"a\"]]"
[3] "qux[[\"foo\"]]; bar[[\"baz\"]]; x[[\"uvw\"]]"                  
[4] "qux[[\"fo o\"]]"                                               
[5] "q_ux[[\"f_o_o\"]][[\"b.a_r\"]]"
```

Note: backslashes in the output are console artifacts to keep the double quoted strings valid string literals, they are not part of the plain text output.

Comment: There's a problem when there is a period: ```gsub('(\\w*)(?|\\$(\\w+)|\\$`([^`]*)`)', '\\1[["\\2"]]', 'q_ux$f_o_o$b.a_r', perl=TRUE)``` gives `q_ux[["f_o_o"]][["b"]].a_r`.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Then match one or more chars other than a `$` and whitespace after `$`.

Comment: Thanks. Another issue: that doesn't work when there is more than one space between the backticks, e.g. ```'q_ux$f_o_o$b.a_r$`x  y`'```. Sorry for my poor skills in regex....

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I noticed, it is due to the order of the alternatives, they should have been swapped. Also, I see the pattern can be simplified due to the fact you do not need to match the leading word chars, they do not set any context and can be removed from the pattern.

Comment: Hi again Wiktor. There's a problem with the semi-colon. Look at [2] in your output, the semi-colon is inside the brackets.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent What are the characters you allow/diasallow after `$`? If you have exact specs, this can be answered. Right now, not knowing what there can be, I am using the negation logic and would match any chars other than `$`, `;` and whitespace, ``gsub('\\$`([^`]*)`|\\$([^\\s;$]+)', '[["\\1\\2"]]', x, perl=TRUE)``, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dwnCkL/7).

Answer (score 1):

You might repeat optional spaces before and after matching 1 or more word characters.

You don't need a capture group for the `$` but instead you could use a capture group to pair up the backtick in case it is there or not using a backreference to group 2.

To repeat 0+ whitespace chars you can also use `\s` but that could also match a newline.

Note that `\w*` matches optional word chars, and `{0,1}` can be written as `?`

```
(\w*)\$(`?)( *\w+(?: +\w+)* *)\2
```

The pattern matches:

- `(\w*)` Capture **group 1** Match optional word characters
- `\$` Match `$`
- `` (`?) `` Capture **group 2**, optionally match a backtick
- `( *\w+(?: +\w+)* *)` Capture **group 3** Match repetitions of word characters between spaces
- `\2` Backreference to what is captured in group 2 (yes or no backtick)

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JDTYqR/1)

```
gsub("(\\w*)\\$(`?)( *\\w+(?: +\\w+)* *)\\2", '\\1[["\\3"]]', "qux$fo o$bar", perl=TRUE)
```

Output

```
[1] "qux[[\"fo o\"]][[\"bar\"]]"
```

Comment: Thanks. Good but that does not work for the "chained" situation: ```gsub("(\\w*)\\$(`?)( *(?:\\w+ *)+)\\2", '\\1[["\\3"]]', "qux$`fo o`$bar")``` gives `qux[["fo o"]][["b"]]ar`.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I see, you have to add `PERL=TRUE` I have updated the answer.

Comment: Better! But still doesn't work for ```'qux$`fo o`$bar$`s  x`'```.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent If there are multiple spaces, you can use a quantifier. See the updated answer.

Comment: Better (+1).  There's the same problem as in the other answer, when there is a period : ```"qux$`fo o`$b.a_r"``` gives `qux[["fo o"]][["b"]].a_r`.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent You can add more accepted characters to the character class ``(\w*)\$(`?)( *\w+(?:[._ ]+\w+)* *)\2`` see https://regex101.com/r/uGW6sk/1 and the ouput [here](https://ideone.com/54Gt6T)

Comment: Yes, looks perfect! Thanks!

Comment: Hi again, the fourth bird. If I transform  ```input$foo + input$bar```, I get ```input[["foo "]]+ input[["bar"]]```. Do you know how to solve that?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent You can add the plus to the accepted characters. See https://regex101.com/r/VdI2G2/1

Comment: No, the expected result is `input[["foo"]] + input[["bar"]]`.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Ah you mean like this ``(\w*)\$(`?)( *\w+(?:[._ ]+\w+)*)\2`` without matching spaces after the last word character https://regex101.com/r/IqdIT1/1

Comment: PERFECT the fourth bird!!! I'm doing a RStudio addin using your regex.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Cool, you could change the spaces to match horizontal whitespace chars for a broader range if you want. ``(\w*)\$(`?)(\h*\w+(?:[._\h]+\w+)*)\2`` See https://regex101.com/r/dyDFMv/1 and https://ideone.com/XbAf0K

Comment: The fourth bird, [here is the package](https://github.com/stla/bracketify). I don't see the difference with your latest regex.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Using `\h` could also match for example a tab.